# Magento Theme css color not changing

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, css

I am new to **Magento** & using **Magento 2.1.7** in my system I have installed a theme in my Magento & now when I am changing the background color in my theme's CSS it is not showing any change in that & while in the inspect element the classes & the CSS the theme is accessing it is not present in the CSS that is located in the `web/css` folder of the theme

here is the Image how it is showing in inspect element.

[image: theme color not changing]

here in this image, the color showing in the css is with code `#ff3366` & in the CSS of this theme I have replaced it with `#ff6600` but still, it is showing here as `#ff3366`

I am not able to find the exact solution please anyone can help?

Comment: It looks like it can be set on admin panal. If not, search for CSS with class `.magicmenu`, should be somewhere in your theme. Then modify the styles and follow @samani instructions.

Comment: It depends on the theme. You may look at user manual of the theme.

Comment: Please run upgrade and deploy command..

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in your terminal

```
 1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
 2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
 3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
 4. Then delete folder (var/cache , var/di, var/page_cache/, var/generation/, var/view_preprocessed/) in your project
 5. refresh the page
```